# Get SORTED array after using orderBy Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have an array I have sorted with the Angular orderBy command in my html.  I need to retrieve the items in the list in the order in which they are sorted.  Is there a way to do this?

using $scope.people[] ng-repeat makes a table as follows:

```
Original
id    name
2     bob
4     joe
1     dave

After sorting I get
id    name
1     dave
2     bob
4     joe
```

Now I want to be able to access $scope.people[] but in the sorted order.  Is this possible?

Comment: You could run the same orderBy filter in the controller - $filter('orderBy')(array, expression, reverse). Not sure if that will be practical for you though depending on how many ways you let people sort.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Angular 1.3.x** added `"alias"` expression which will store the intermediate results of the repeater after the filters have been applied.

```
    <div ng-repeat='p in people | orderBy : "name" as result'>
        {{p.name}}
    </div>

    <p> <b>Original</b></p>
    <div>{{people || json}}</div>

    <p><b>Sorted</b></p>
    <div>{{result || json }}</div>
```

[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/eU8qWtExgXwSTXfWqdfP?p=preview)